# DocuSign Rest API returning blank response after moving into production environment (same code works fine in Sandbox)

Tags: curl, docusignapi

We have all code working in the Sandbox.  We have completing all the steps to move to production successfully at Docusign.  Docusign Rest API is returning a blank response after moving into production environment (same code works fine in Sandbox)

After Purchasing 'Basic API' Plan with Docusign we are attempting to use same curl scripts that were working fine in Sandbox environment in Production.  Used GetUserInfo to determine the base URI (ca.docusign.net), tried restapi/v2/ , restapi/v2.1/ and also tried without specifying a version, always get a blank response (unless we send an invalid bearer token, see #3 below). Production Token string seems to be fine as GetUserInfo works in production and no authorization errors.

1) Sandbox (works fine, API returns an Envelope ID):
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenTextString]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @JsonReq.txt  --request POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account_id]/envelopes  -k
{
  "envelopeId": "6e1aa70d-cc9e-4a57-a371-1deed8e49424",
  "uri": "/envelopes/6e1aa70d-cc9e-4a57-a371-1deed8e49424",
  "statusDateTime": "2020-01-14T15:32:38.9230000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}

2) Production Environment (Get Blank Response):
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenTextString]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @T:\at\oct2017!docusign\JsonReq.txt  --request POST https://ca.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account_id]/envelopes  -k

3) Interestingly If I change the bearer token to something invalid (ie remove the leading 'e') I get a response "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED":

curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenTextString_e_removed]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @T:\at\oct2017!docusign\JsonReq.txt  --request POST https://ca.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account_id]/envelopes  -k
{
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}

Note: used the userinfo request to get the Base URI for the Production RestAPI (ca.docusign.net)

curl  --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenTextString]"  --request GET https://account.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo  -k
{"sub":"21219113-31d7-427d-bdad-16dab4654485","name":"XXXX XXXX","given_name":"XXXX","family_name":"xxxx","created":"2019-12-10T22:18:51.623","email":
"xxxx@xxxxx.com","accounts":[{"account_id":"[account_id]","is_default":true,"account_name":"XXXXXX Inc","base_uri":"https://ca.docusign.net"}]}

Comment: how do you obtain the production token? do you use Auth Code Grant? JWT?

Comment: The Production Token is obtained using script below:
curl --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=[Encoded_JWT]" --request POST https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token -k
{"access_token":"[TokenText]","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}

Comment: you do need an IK and RSA Keypair for production, do you have all of that? you also need the userId for the user in prod.

Comment: Yes I have a production Integration Key and Created the RSA keypair in Admin>'API & Keys' > Authentication > Service Integration and followed the steps to get the bearer token. The API seems to be accepting the token, because if I use an expired token with same RestAPI request (that was previously returning blank) I get error {
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}

Comment: so it's the call to ca.docusign.net that gets you the blank response?

Comment: can you try API v2.1

Comment: Yes, it is the call to ca.docusign.net that gets you the blank response.  I tried v2.1 and still got blank response, is this the correct way to point to use v2.1 in Production?
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenText]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @JsonReq.txt  --request POST https://ca.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[Account-ID]/envelopes  -k

Comment: can you try the same call to www.docusign.net instead of ca.docusign.net (everything else the same). Trying to isolate the issue here.

Comment: Tried same call with www.docusign.net , got blank response
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [TokenText]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @JsonReq.txt  --request POST https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[AcctID]/envelopes  -k

Comment: DaveD, please send me an email with your accountID (GUID) and we'll try to investigate this. inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: sent  you the email from my jsitsp.com account, Thanks for looking into this

Comment: @DaveD Do you get any response status code in POST /envelope API call? Also please check [Encoded_JWT] if correct sub, issuer, "aud" as account.docusign.com and correct "scope" as "impersonation signature" is added while creating access token.

Comment: No, the response is blank for the envelope API Call. Inbar Gazit checked the logs on docusign side and doesn't see the requests getting to the server.  If I use an invalid token I will get the response below. When token ok, no reposnse {
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}

Comment: did you try using POSTMAN to call PROD endpoint for /envelopes API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared all the settings on every screen between my Sandbox and Live Accounts side-by-side, Found that when the Integration key was copied to the live account,  the Authentication must have got defaulted to 'Authorization Code Grant' (Docusign GO-live Process)
After updating to 'Implicit Grant' and going through the steps again (RSA Keys / JWT gen etc) was able to get a successful Envelope request through.
What threw everything off is the docusign API was returning no response instead of on error (unless the bearer token was invalid or expired then would get an error response) had an error been returned would have clued in earlier that need to go through the settings with fine toothed comb.

Comment: This helped me out! I was experiencing the same situation, thank you!